# Systemd service not working

Tags: systemd

Could anyone figure out why this systemd unit fails to start?

I have placed the service in `/etc/systemd/system/startup_actions.service`

```
[Unit]  
Description=Startup actions

[Service]
Type=oneshot 
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/disable_pgupdw.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To run it I do

```
sudo systemctl start startup_actions.service
```

The unit symply disables the pgup and down keys with xmodmap, and works on its own:

```
#!/bin/bash
xmodmap -e 'keycode 112 = NoSymbol'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 117 = NoSymbol'
```

The script is placed in

```
/usr/local/bin
```

This is the output of systemctl status startup_actions

```
startup_actions.service - Startup actions
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/startup_actions.service; enabled; vendor preset: enable
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-11-04 14:15:18 GMT; 1h 21min ago
Process: 2360 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/disable_pgupdw.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 2360 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

When I try to start it it says:

```
Job for startup_actions.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status startup_actions.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
```

Comment: Have you done 'systemctl daemon-reload' ? What does it say when you try to start it? What's output of the 'systemctl status startup_actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following unit works, even though it is not the optimal solution

```
[Unit]  
Description=Startup actions

[Service]
Type=simple
User=USERNAME
Environment=DISPLAY=:0 
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/disable_pgupdw.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

One in fact needs to add a sleep 10 at the beginning of the script, which is not very nice

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10
xmodmap -e 'keycode 112 = NoSymbol'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 117 = NoSymbol'
```

As pointed out by Ignacio, xmodmap requires access to the X server. The combination

```
Type=simple
User=USERNAME
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
```

and

```
sleep 10
```

in the script seems to achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The same unit work for me when I put it in `~user/.config/systemd/user/` ( then `systemctl --user daemon-reload` ) and starting it using `systemctl --user start startup_actions.service`.
This ways environment variables are properly sets.